# Secure Login Form, and Register Form(w/ serial key)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, authentication

Sorry, im kind of new to making stuff like databases(mysql) and such, but I was wondering if someone can provide me with a link to a tutorial on making a login form, register form, and the register form requiring a serial key I provide. I've searched for about an hour and haven't found anything, it could have been my search words. I want to know how to make a database login where my users can register with a *Username*, *Password*, and *Serial Key* that I provide them and apply it to their username so they can successfully login. Sorry, if im not clear, im pretty new here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic thing. You have design form then why not code it ?
Every control has events. if you design the forms means you know the logic behind it.
just go ahead. here are some steps that will help you.

1. Validate empty Username and password textbox.
2. Make SQL connection and Fetch password with the help of username
3. if no record fetch alert user "Userid not exist"
4. if record exist check against entered password, if mismatched, alert user "Wrong password"
   Hi Please find below Links for your qustions

[Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwSgCi0mGRQ)

[Link2](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/217409/sample-c-windows-form-login-screen)